# Problema generando divs con append

Tags: javascript

¡Hola, buenas!

Tengo que entregar este proyecto de la universidad y me estoy volviendo loco porque no consigo que aparezcan los divs que necesito :/ Seguro que el código tiene muchos más fallos (y no me voy a quejar si alguien se dedica a señalarlos, obviamente :D), pero el que mas me preocupa ahora mismo es ese.

Es un juego de cartas en el que varios jugadores tienen que ir sacando cartas (cada uno de su propia baraja) hasta que tres de esas cartas coincidan en número (por ejemplo, tres ases, tres doses, etc.). El que lo haga en menor numero de cartas, gana. Hay que mostrar las cartas (pueden aparecer de una en una o todas a la vez, he optado por la segunda opción), los nombres y la puntuación de los jugadores, además de guardarla en localStorage. ¿Me podéis echar un cable?

Aquí os dejo el fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pnn5jtdh/ y el JS en si:

```
//creo los tipos de variables de los números, los palos y la baraja
var cards = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
var suits = ["diamonds", "hearts", "spades", "clubs"];
var deck = new Array();
var player = new Array();

function getDeck()
{
    var deck = new Array();
//cargar la baraja de cartas
    for(var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x < cards.length; x++)
        {
            var card = {Value: cards[x], Suit: suits[i]};
            deck.push(card);
        }
    }

    return deck;
}

function deal()
{
    // sacar la última carta de la baraja
    var card = deck[deck.length-1];
    deck.splice(deck.length-1, 1);
    return card;
}

function shuffle()
{
    // cambiar dos cartas aleatorias de posición 1000 veces
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var location1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.length));
        var location2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.length));
        var tmp = deck[location1];

        deck[location1] = deck[location2];
        deck[location2] = tmp;
    }
}

function renderDeck(deck, number)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)
    {
        var card = document.createElement("div");
        var value = document.createElement("div");
        var suit = document.createElement("div");
        card.className = "card";
        value.className = "value";
        suit.className = "suit " + deck[i].Suit;

        value.innerHTML = deck[i].Value;
        card.appendChild(value);
        card.appendChild(suit);

        document.getElementById("deck"+number).appendChild(card);
    }
}

function game(deck) {

     var cont= new array();
     for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    //creo un contador para cada uno de los números de la baraja
    cont[i]=0;}

     //contador de puntuacion
     var score = 0;

     //creo una nueva baraja para contener las cartas que voy sacando
     var newDeck = "";

     //mientras ninguno de los contadores llegue a 3, el juego continua
     while (cont[1] < 3 || cont[2] < 3 || cont[3] < 3 || cont[4] < 3 || cont[5] < 3 || cont[6] < 3|| cont[7] < 3 || cont[8] < 3 || cont[9] < 3 || cont[10] < 3) {

         //saco la última carta de la baraja
         newDeck[score]= deck.pop();

         //busco a qué valor corresponde la carta y subo la cuenta de su contador correspondiente
        if (newDeck[score].value = 1) {
            cont[1]++;}

        else if (newDeck[score].value = 2) {
            cont[2]++;}

        else if (newDeck[score].value = 3) {
            cont[3]++;}

        else if (newDeck[score].value = 4) {
            cont[4]++;}

        else if (newDeck[score].value = 5) {
            cont[5]++;}

        else if (newDeck[score].value = 6) {
            cont[6]++;}

        else if (newDeck[score].value = 7) {
            cont[7]++;}

        else if (newDeck[score].value = 8) {
            cont[8]++;}

        else if (newDeck[score].value = 9) {
            cont[9]++;}

        else {
            cont[10]++;}

         //aumento el contador de puntuación
         score++;
     }

     //devuelvo la puntuación y el mazo con las cartas resultantes
     return score, newDeck;
}

function players (){

    //pregunto cuántos jugadores serán      
        var number = prompt("¿Cuántas personas van a jugar?","2");

        //en función de cuántos sean, creo el mismo número de prompts para preguntar sus nombres
        //y almacenarlos en localStorage

        for(var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            player[i]= prompt("¿Cómo se llama el jugador número " + i + "?");
        }
        //dado que localStorage solo me permite guardar Strings, utilizo stringify para pasar el array
        localStorage.setItem('nickName', JSON.stringify(player));

        //devuelvo el array de jugadores
        return player;}


function myFunction()
{
    players();

    for (var i= 0; i< player.lenght; i++) {
        //crear un div para meter la información de cada jugador
    var playerTitle = document.createElement("div");
    var playerName = document.createTextNode(player[i]); 
    playerTitle.appendChild(playerName);
    playerTitle.classname = "playerTitle";

    document.getElementById("results").appendChild(playerTitle);

    var deckShow = document.createElement("div");
    deckShow.id = "deck" +i;
    document.getElementById("results").appendChild(deckShow);
}

    //realizo el juego para cada jugador
for (var i = 0; i < player.lenght; i++) {


    //inicializar las barajas
    deck[i] = getDeck();
    shuffle();


    //crear el juego
    game(deck[i]);
    console.log(game);
    //mostrar la baraja
    renderDeck(newDeck, i);
    //guardar la puntuación en un array para pasarlo a localStorage
    var finalScore = "";
    finalScore[i]=score;

    //mostrar el resultado
    document.getElementById("playerTitle" + i).innerHTML = player[i] + " ha conseguido su objetivo en " + score + "turnos.";

    //genero una tupla para poder consultar el ganador
    const winner = (player[i], score)

    //paso el array a localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('score', JSON.stringify(finalScore));

    //determino el ganador

    console.log(players);
    console.log(deck);


    }
    var which = Math.min(...winner.score);
    for (var i = 0; i < player.lenght; i++) {
        if (which==winner[i].score) {

        document.getElementById("finalScore").innerHTML = "El ganador es " + winner[i].player;
        }
        else {}
    }





}
```

Comment: Hola, tienes para empezar un error cuando has nombrado a los jugadores ; `cartas.js:195 Uncaught ReferenceError: winner is not defined
    at myFunction (cartas.js:195)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (cartas.html:15)`